# Count combinations of packages (row values) per user (unique value)

Tags: postgresql

Consider the following:

```
customer, package
a, pack1
a, pack2
b, pack1
c, pack1
c, pack2
d, pack3
d, pack2
d, pack1
e, pack1
e, pack3
f, pack1
f, pack2
f, pack3
```

The output I need is, how MANY unique customers have a SPECIFIC combination of package(s):

```
 pack1, 1 
(pack1, pack2), 2
(pack1, pack2, pack3), 2
(pack1, pack3), 1
```

When I export the table to a spreadsheet (or use GNU datamash) and make a pivot table and work a little bit on that, I can sort of get what I need, but I need to count things by hand. So I keep thinking this should be simpler (without exporting the data to a pivot table).

Any pointers are appreciated (it's late).

There is an SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7bb98/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the packages into a single string (ordered by package) for each customer, then you can count by that concatenated string:

For Postgres:

```
select packs, count(*)
from (
    select cust, string_agg(package,',' order by package) packs
    from  Table1
    group by cust
    ) p
group by packs    
;
```

results

```
|             packs | count |
|-------------------|-------|
|       pack1,pack3 |     1 |
|       pack1,pack2 |     2 |
| pack1,pack2,pack3 |     2 |
|             pack1 |     1 |
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/acf27/1)

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I only had to change string_agg(package...) to string_agg(package::character varying...). For the example I wasn't totally true-to-life, because my packages are actually integers also. But with this little addition it works fantastic!